# How to use jquery.when with ember data promises

Tags: jquery, ember.js, ember-data, promise, deferred

I'm trying to fire a callback when multiple ember models have finished their save methods.

```
var promises = [];
modellist.forEach(function(mymodel){
    promises.push(mymodel.save())
}
$.when.apply(null, promises).done(function () {
    console.log('finished promises');
}
console.log('finished method');
```

The apply function is executed immediately.

Question: Which of the following is true?

- promise != ember-promise
- promise != deferred
- ember-promise != deferred

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a big fan of [`RSVP.hash`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/RSVP.html#method_hash) as it allows an object, while `RSVP.all` uses an array.

If you want to use it in regular code to save multiple models.

```
actions: {
   doSomething() {
     Ember.RSVP.hash({
       model1Saved: this.get('model1').save(),
       model2Saved: this.get('model2').save(),
    }).then((hash) => { 
      /* hash.model1Saved and hash.model2Saved are available here */ 
    }, (error) => { 
     /* Deal with error */ 
    });
   }
}
```

Which is nice, because you don't have to mess with array indexes.

Also when returning a model for the route

```
model() {
return Ember.RSVP.hash({
  posts: this.store.findAll('post'),
  tags: this.store.findAll('tag'),
  categories: this.store.findAll('category'),
});
},
```

And then in the setupController method you can:

```
setupController(controller, model) {
  this._super(controller, model.posts);
  controller.set('tags', model.tags);
  controller.set('category', model.categories);
}
```

Comment: Glad I could help! Good luck with your Ember app!

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution:

- Ember.RSVP.all(promises).then(function(){...})

This was not easy to find in the docs :-(